# Internal server error 500 crashes server laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

Every time there is 500 error server cpu gets 100% and crashes needs to restart every time

```
PHP Version 7.4
Laravel Version 8.83
Ubuntu Ngnix
```

I found this in php7.4-fpm.log error logs

```
[13-Sep-2022 08:13:16] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[13-Sep-2022 08:19:05] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[13-Sep-2022 08:19:05] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
```

error.log

```
2022/09/13 10:52:53 [error] 889#889: *3130 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
2022/09/13 11:09:41 [crit] 889#889: *148 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking
```

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Look at your error log, PHP and maybe Apache as well

Comment: Every time I gets 500 error even for  minor issue servers crashes

Comment: You dont get 500 errors for minor issues

Comment: No @RiggsFolly its keeps on loading and server goes to 100% cpu

Comment: Typo? Ubuntu or CentOs?

Comment: Typo Ubuntu Ngnix

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP-FPM config is set to the default `5` children (simultaneously executing PHP requests) and that limit is (on occasion it appears) being exceeded and hence the `500` error. Have a read of [this article](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-change-the-php-fpm-max_children-setting/) if you want background knowledge on the PHP-FPM `max_children` setting.

There is also a [handy online calculator](https://spot13.com/pmcalculator/) for calculating a more appropriate `max_children` value for your server configuration.

Once you have calculated a new (higher) value for the setting, you'll need to update your PHP-FPM configuration and reset the PHP-FPM service on your server for the change to take effect.

Comment: But I have another staging server with same config and it works fine there server doesn't get crashes on 500 error , its says "The main risk of increasing max_children is that each additional PHP process uses additional memory, so your server needs more memory as you increase max_children."

Comment: @SukhwinderSodhi Does your staging server have the exact same hardware and service configuration? Does it receive the same number of incoming requests etc.? Yes, there are risks when increasing the `max_children` value. It is down to you to decide if that risk offsets the server crash and what value to use to limit the risk.

Comment: Its same hardware and service config but incoming requests are different. Okay thanks I will go through whole article and check